# A heterogenous array in array of records ***.* is not supported. Warning: Undeclared variable or command: ***.*

Tags: modelica, dymola

I have a very simple fluid model : a source, a meshed pipe, a sink.
Dymola (2024x) choose, among the initialization variables, the value of the enthalpy `h` in some of the nodes. However the initial value is not good enough to find a solution and the solver fails to initialize the simulation.

I know a better guess value and I achieve in initializing the simulation by adding `h(each start=my_better_value)` in te text of my model but I did not found any way to provide just the value in the specific node Dymola is asking.

For example, in the variable browser, among the `initial values`, Dymola only shows the `my_module.h[2]`. However, if I try to modify this sole value I get the following messages in the command panel and my change does not take effect:

```
A heterogenous array in array of records my_module.h is not supported. 
Warning: Undeclared variable or command: my_module.h
```

Why is this happening? I am pretty sure of having independently modified the values of an array in the past...
What else can I do to set the initial value (instead of the `each start` command)?

**EDIT - Actual example**

This is an "elementary" test case to reproduce the issue. It is based on the ThermoSysPro library.

```
model BOP
  ThermoSysPro.Fluid.BoundaryConditions.SourceQ sourceQ(
    Q0=10,
    T0=500);

  ThermoSysPro.Fluid.BoundaryConditions.SinkP sinkP;

  ThermoSysPro.Fluid.HeatExchangers.DynamicOnePhaseFlowPipe
    dynamicOnePhaseFlowPipe(
    Ns=1,
    h(each start=2.e6));
equation 
  connect(dynamicOnePhaseFlowPipe.C1, sourceQ.C);
  connect(dynamicOnePhaseFlowPipe.C2, sinkP.C);
end BOP;
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example? I have never seen this error message.
In general, fixed initialization of array elements can be done with alias variables or initial equations. You want to set guess values (`fixed=false`), right?. I think this is not possible, but maybe I have an idea when I see a minimal example.

Comment: I modified my question to include an exemple, not so "elementary" since it is based on the ThermoSysPro library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is only expected to occur if my_module is also an array (of components) where each element has an array h of a different length.

Like the following:

```
  model MyModule
    parameter Integer n;
    Real h[n];
  equation 
    sin(h)+1e-3*h=zeros(n); // Non-linear system
  end MyModule;
  MyModule my_module[2](n={2,1});
```

It might be that it can also occur for just a plain array in some very rare cases, but we would need the model to see why.

The work-around is similar in both cases - introduce a new alias to the specific element and give it a start-value:

```
 Real x(start=...)=my_module[1].h[1];
```

And you should then be able to set the start-value of `x` after translation in the usual way.

Comment: I added an example (based on ThermoSysPro) to my question. I do not see how I would have nested arrays...
However, the "workaround" of adding an alias works to modify a unique value of an array (even if it looks like I cannot modify its value once the model is compiled: it has to be hardcoded in the model).